# How to retrieve a Person's Names, Emails, Phone Numbers from Google's People

Tags: php, google-people-api

I have been trying to retrieve a person's Names, Emails, and Phone Numbers from Google's People API. I can only get the Names so far. Any attempts at retrieving any other values cause everything to stop working.

The code below works well. The other one fails.

What am I doing wrong, or missing?

Thank you all in advance.

**WORKING FINE :**

```
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

// Print the names for up to 10 connections.
$optParams = array('pageSize' => 10, 'personFields' => 'names,phoneNumbers',);

$results = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);

if (count($results->getConnections()) == 0) {
    echo "No connections found.\n";
} else {
    echo "People:\n";
    foreach ($results->getConnections() as $person) {
        if (count($person->getNames()) == 0) {
            $persPrint = json_encode($person, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            echo '<div>No names found for this connection <pre>' . $persPrint . '</pre></div>';
        } else {
            $names = $person->getNames();
            $name = $names[0];

            echo '<div>' . $name->getDisplayName() . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

**NOT WORKING :**

```
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

// Print the names for up to 10 connections.
$optParams = array('pageSize' => 10, 'personFields' => 'names,phoneNumbers',);

$results = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);

if (count($results->getConnections()) == 0) {
    echo "No connections found.\n";
} else {
    echo "People:\n";
    foreach ($results->getConnections() as $person) {
        if (count($person->getNames()) == 0) {
            $persPrint = json_encode($person, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            echo '<div>No names found for this connection <pre>' . $persPrint . '</pre></div>';
        } else {
            $names = $person->getNames();
            $name = $names[0];

            $phoneNumbers = $person->getPhoneNumbers();
            $phoneNumber = '';

            if (sizeof($phoneNumbers[0]) > 0) {
                $phoneNumber = $phoneNumbers[0];

                echo $phoneNumber->getFormattedType();
            }

            echo '<div>' . $name->getDisplayName() . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there @Program-Me-Rev! I am trying to understand what is wrong with the faulty code. Could you please elaborate why it doesn't reach your goals? Please share any error messages if you get them.

Comment: Hi there @jacques-guzel-heron. Thank you for the reply. I managed to get it working. I'll be updating the question with the working code.